# Better way to deserialize Minecraft json

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, deserialization

I am trying to work with **Minecraft json** from ([1.8.json download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.8.json)).  A Sample:

```
{
  "objects": {
    "realms/lang/de_DE.lang": {
      "hash": "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194",
      "size": 7784
    },
    "realms/lang/cy_GB.lang": {
      "hash": "7b52463b2df4685d2d82c5d257fd5ec79843d618",
      "size": 7688
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/blaze/breathe4.ogg": {
      "hash": "78d544a240d627005aaef6033fd646eafc66fe7a",
      "size": 22054
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/dig/sand4.ogg": {
      "hash": "37afa06f97d58767a1cd1382386db878be1532dd",
      "size": 5491
    }
  }
}
```

The actual json is much longer, some 2940 lines.

I need a way to deserialize this that isn't completely insane - using JSONUtils I get 4411 Lines of Code, but the same code can't be used for any other version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automated tools can be very useful, but they are not perfect - especially when it comes to dictionaries.

The first thing to note is that the structure is the same for all of them, that is they all consist of `hash` and `size` properties.  This means rather than creating hundreds of identical classes we can use the same one over and over:

```vb
' the type that repeats from your robot:
Public Class MinecraftItem
    Public Property hash As String
    Public Property size As Int32
End Class
```

Since the automated tools are working on the fly (they do not look ahead...or back) they don't really know that they are all the same.  The next thing is that the classes the robots generate wont work in this case:

```vb
Public Property minecraft/sounds/music/game/creative/creative3.ogg As _
            MinecraftSoundsMusicGameCreativeCreative3Ogg
```

That is illegal as a property name.  However, the names will work just fine as Dictionary keys. In addition to the above `MinecraftItem` class, we *might* want a container class:

```vb
Public Class MinecraftContainer
    Public objects As Dictionary(Of String, MinecraftItem)
End Class
```

There are (at least) 3 ways to get at the data:

#### Method 1: Pluck out a single item

```vb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim jstr As String = ...from whereever

' parse the json into a JObject
Dim js As JObject = JObject.Parse(jstr)

' if you somehow know the names, you can pluck out the data:
Dim mi = js("objects")("minecraft/sounds/mob/blaze/hit2.ogg")

Console.WriteLine(mi("hash").ToString & "    " & mi("size").ToString)
```

The first line parses the original json string into a JObject.  This allows us to work with the contents in various ways.  For instance, we can reference "objects" in the json and them the items by name, which is exactly what happens in the next line:

```vb
' drill into "objects", get the "...hit2.ogg" item
Dim mi = js("objects")("minecraft/sounds/mob/blaze/hit2.ogg")
```

This will work if you just need to fetch a particular item from the big file. The `mi` variable created is a "special" json token, so use the names to get the data bits you want

```vb
hash = mi("hash").ToString
size = mi("size").ToString
```

#### Method 2: Deserialize To a Dictionary

This would be *my* preferred method.  Include the same `Import` statements as in the first example, then:

```vb
' parse the json string
Dim js As JObject = JObject.Parse(jstr)

' deserialize the inner "objects" to a NET Dictionary
Dim myItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, _
                   MinecraftItem))(js("objects").ToString)
```

This will create `myItems` as a Net `Dictionary(Of String, MincraftItem)` from the json.  Since the `MinecraftObject` class doesn't do *anything* but hold the dictionary, we skipped it.

The keys are the long names and each value is a `MinecraftItem` which allows you to reference them more conventionally:

```vb
' get one of the items into a variable
gravel3 = myItems("minecraft/sounds/mob/chicken/step2.ogg")
ConsoleWriteLine("Gravel3  hash: {0},  size: {1}",
                      gravel3.hash, gravel3.size.ToString)
```

If you are not familiar with the [.Net Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) it is somewhat like an array or List except you access your items by a `Key` rather then index.  To loop thru them all:

```vb
Dim n As Integer = 0
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, MinecraftItem) In myItems
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}  Hash: {1}  size: {2}",
                      kvp.Key, 
                      kvp.Value.hash, 
                      kvp.Value.size.ToString)
    n += 1
    If n >= 2 Then Exit For           ' just print 3
Next
```

Output:

> Name: realms/lang/de_DE.lang Hash: 10a54fc66c8f479bb65c8d39c3b62265ac82e742 size: 8112
>   Name: realms/lang/cy_GB.lang Hash: 14cfb2f24e7d91dbc22a2a0e3b880d9829320243 size: 7347
>   Name: minecraft/sounds/mob/chicken/step2.ogg Hash: bf7fadaf64945f6b31c803d086ac6a652aabef9b size: 3838

Just remember, the Key will always be the long path name, and each `.Value` *is* `MinecraftItem` object.

#### Method 3: Deserialize To a Container

You can skip the parsing step by using the `MinecraftContainer` class:

```vb
Dim jstr As String = ...from whereever
Dim myJItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MinecraftContainer)(jstr)
```

Note that this time, you pass *the entire string you downloaded* to `JsonConvert`.  The result will be an extra outer object which contains a dictionary property named "Objects".  So, you reference the items using some leading references:

```vb
gravel3hash = myJItems.Object("minecraft/sounds/dig/gravel3.ogg").hash

gravel3 = myJItems.Object("minecraft/sounds/dig/gravel3.ogg")
    ConsoleWriteLine("Gravel3  hash: {0},  size: {1}",
                      gravel3.hash, gravel3.size.ToString)
'or:
ConsoleWriteLine("Gravel3  hash: {0},  size: {1}",
                   myJItems.Object("minecraft/sounds/dig/gravel3.ogg").hash, 
                   myJItems.Object("minecraft/sounds/dig/gravel3.ogg").size.ToString)
```

This method is just one line of code to deserialize, but it means
  a) I have to define the container class and
  b) I have to use `myJItems.Object` to drill into the otherwise empty container to get at the Dictionary.

Personally, I would forego this and use method 2 - one extra line of code makes it a bit easier to work with.  That said, you can also extract the dictionary collection from the container:

```vb
Dim myItems As Dictionary(Of String, MinecraftItem)= myJItems.Object
```