# obtain values to json file

Tags: json, vb.net

I am making an application in vb net, and read JSON format files.
I know how, but I have a file that has a different format, you can see here:

```
{
  "objects": {
    "realms/lang/de_DE.lang": {
      "hash": "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194",
      "size": 7784
    },
    "realms/lang/cy_GB.lang": {
      "hash": "7b52463b2df4685d2d82c5d257fd5ec79843d618",
      "size": 7688
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/blaze/breathe4.ogg": {
      "hash": "78d544a240d627005aaef6033fd646eafc66fe7a",
      "size": 22054
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/dig/sand4.ogg": {
      "hash": "37afa06f97d58767a1cd1382386db878be1532dd",
      "size": 5491
    }
  }
}
```

It is different because all text has objects, no string, so I can not read it defined classes.
I just need the values of "hash", then add them to a textbox.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you need *just* the hashes, or do you need the hashes and the filename associated with each hash?

Comment: Parse it then deserialize "objects" to a `Dictionary(Of String, MinecraftItem)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to deserialize this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084143/better-way-to-deserialize-this)

Comment: Mark's got the non-evil solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like @Plutonix has seen this before, so I'll go with the Minecraft thing.  It seems like `objects` is a `Dictionary(Of String, MinecraftItem)`.  A little tweak to the linked duplicate could be to create a class for the whole file, so you don't have to pull out the `objects` separately:

```
Public Class MinecraftData
    Public Property Objects As Dictionary(Of String, MinecraftItem)
End Class

Public Class MinecraftItem
    Public Property Hash As String
    Public Property Size As Long
End Class
```

You can then parse the whole thing using Json.NET:

```
Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MinecraftData)(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **certain** that you will **only ever need the hashes**, you can actually use a regex to get all the hashes from this file.  Yes, this is slightly evil, because regex is normally not a suitable tool for dealing with structured data.  But if you don't care about the structure...

```
Dim hashExtractor = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9a-f]{40}")
Dim matches = hashExtractor.Matches(myFileContents).Cast(of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match)
Dim hashes = matches.Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()
```