# Parsing JSON Objects within JSON arrays within JSON Objects in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

Hello Everyone and thanks for looking at this. I'm relatively new to vb.net and extremely new to parsing json in vb. I am using JSON.Net and I'm looking to gather data from the following JSON.

http://hastebin.com/bagiyetece.apache

I have classes created for each of the "sections". I am unsure of the correct terminology.

Class One:

```
Public Class StatsWrapper
    Public SummonerID as Long
    Public PlayerStatSummaries as playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper
End Class
```

Class Two:

```
Public Class playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper
    Public playerStatSummaryType As String
    Public wins As Long
    Public modifyDate As Long
    Public aggregatedStats As aggregatedStatsWrapper
End Class
```

Class Three:

http://hastebin.com/qopanafabe.php

My end goal is to be able to get elements like "totalChampionKills" for the playerStatSummaryType of "Cap5x5" and insert them into a datagridview.

I've been able to correctly parse the following JSON simply by using JObject.Parse.

```
{"UserName":{"id":84737282,"name":"UserName","profileIconId":660,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1455686689000}}
```

To get the id object, I would use:

```
Dim JSONDerulo = JObject.Parse(JSONResponse)
Dim SummonerID = JSONDerulo(LCase(ToolStripTextBox1.Text))("id")
```

Where the ToolStripTextBox1.Text is the UserName.

When I try to apply the same logic as above to the larger JSON file in a different sub:

```
Dim JSONDerulo = JObject.Parse(JSONResponse)
Dim PlayerStatSummaries = JSONDerulo("playerStatSummaries")
Dim Jarray As JArray = PlayerStatSummaries
```

I can do something like:

```
For Each obj As JObject In Jarray
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + obj.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Or call Jarray(1) and parse that again but the list of game types is going to be different for each UserName. I do have a master list for every game type though:

```
AramUnranked5x5, Ascension, Bilgewater, CAP5x5, CoopVsAI, CoopVsAI3x3, CounterPick, FirstBlood1x1, FirstBlood2x2, Hexakill, KingPoro, NightmareBot, OdinUnranked, OneForAll5x5, RankedPremade3x3, RankedPremade5x5, RankedSolo5x5, RankedTeam3x3, RankedTeam5x5, SummonersRift6x6, Unranked, Unranked3x3, URF, URFBots
```

If I want to (for example) call AramUnranked5x5.TotalChampionKills or something similar would I have to create a class for each type?

Any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks Again

Comment: You dont usually need classes if you parse the json, those are used to deserialize back into object(s).  The classes are mostly right - `playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper` should have a `Property losses As Integer`.  You dont need a DGV for one object, a PropertyGrid *might* be a better choice

Comment: Would I be able to use a for loop to deserialize each item in Jarray to a playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper?

Comment: Yes (the top class is slightly off that is an array so `PlayerStatSummaries as playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper()`.  OR deserialize all of them to an array of `playerStatSummaryTypeWrapper`  maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31084143 will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: the json posted is considerably shorter and simpler than the gruesome `aggregatedStatsWrapper` class linked to depicts!  Without data, I cant say whether it is right or not.

Since the `aggregatedStats` is its own type, nothing very interesting will show for it in a DataGridView, just the type name.  There are several ways to handle this.  One is to hide the property from the DGV, then when they change selected/current rows, find the new one in the list and set `player.aggregatedStats` as the selected object in a property grid for a master-detail type view.   Playerstatsummary:

```
Public Class Playerstatsummary
    Public Property playerStatSummaryType As String
    Public Property wins As Integer
    Public Property modifyDate As Long
    <Browsable(False)>
    Public Property aggregatedStats As Aggregatedstats
    Public Property losses As Integer
End Class
```

`<Browsable(False)>` will result in the TypeName not being shown in a DGV:

```
Dim jstr = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\myjsonfilename")

Dim jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr)
Dim players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Playerstatsummary))(jobj("playerStatSummaries").ToString)
```

By Parsing it first, you can skip that outer container. `jobj("playerStatSummaries").ToString` passes the property data to be deserialized into a `List`.

You can display what you have very easily without having to loop at all:

```
dgv1.DataSource = players
```

It wont yet know about `Aggregatedstats` unless and until you work out that class exactly.  Until then, the type name will display.  The post mentions being interested in `Cap5x5` only.  In that case, a `PropertyGrid` might be a better UI mechanism (after you find that guy in the list).  Result:

[image][image]

(This is from before I added `<Browsable(False)>` to the class).  You could show `aggregatedStats` as detail like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(...etc
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then Return

    Dim thisOne = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString

    Dim player = players.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.playerStatSummaryType = thisOne)
    If player IsNot Nothing Then
        PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = player.aggregatedStats
    End If
End Sub
```

In case you are wondering, the date is almost certainly a Unix Epoch date, easily converted to .NET.

Comment: Thanks so much Plutonix!  Do you know of any books/other resources I can read to learn more about vb.net other than simply googling issues as I come across them?

Comment: If this answers the question, please click the checkmark next to the answer. Soon (at 15 rep) you will be able to upvote which you should do for any Q or A which informs, educates, amazes or amuses you.  This helps others find good answers.  For learning, I favor MSDN.  The articles can be dense but they *are* comprehensive and authoritative.  They and the demo code can often at least help you frame the question better,